# Find cells filled with color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with cells filled with red and green colors.How to identify the cells with Red color using a VBA code

Comment: is it conditional formatting or simple fill?

Answer (score 0):

```
If Cells(1).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
```